# Another layout issue on Closed Questions

Tags: bug, closed-questions, user-interface

Comments come before the message:

[image: preview]

Any dupes for this?

Comment: Was this after a manual page reload, or after clicking the "question has been edited, click to reload" prompt?

Comment: Or after clicking the "show 1 more comment" notification? I've seen this with dupe closures after clicking that link.

Comment: It looks correct on the actual question for me, btw.

Comment: @Kendra: So we can rule out manual page loads. (That was my intention...)

Comment: @BoltClock No no. Not a manual page reload.  This is technically after the AJAX call... Ha ha ha. 

Comment: @Kendra Right. That's the way it appears.  Don't reload the page.

Comment: Now seriously I am not sure how I repro'd this.

Comment: Hmm. Now we're going to need to close a bunch more questions to see if we can repro this!

Comment: @CodyGray quickly! To the closemobile! I can't VtC…

Comment: Ha ha ha... `:D`